# Custom email Template issue in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I can't get my custom email class to work with my email template in WooCommerce.

This is the file path for my template:

[Email Template Path Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCQUG.jpg)

This is the bit in my code that calls the template:

```
$this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-approval-order.php';
$this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/customer-approval-order.php';
```

When I use one of the built in templates it works fine, but if I use my custom template it doesn't send an email at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gregor
This is the full code from my custom class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class WC_Email_Customer_Approval_Order file.
 *
 * @package WooCommerce\Emails
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Email_Customer_Approval_Order', false ) ) :

    /**
     * Customer Approval Order Email.
     *
     * An email sent to the customer when a new order is paid for.
     *
     * @class       WC_Email_Customer_Approval_Order
     * @version     2.0.0
     * @package     WooCommerce/Classes/Emails
     * @extends     WC_Email
     */
    class WC_Email_Customer_Approval_Order extends WC_Email {

        /**
         * Constructor.
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $this->id             = 'customer_approval_order';
            $this->customer_email = true;

            $this->title          = __( 'Customer Approval order', 'woocommerce' );
            $this->description    = __( 'This is an order notification sent to customers for approval.', 'woocommerce' );
            $this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-approval-order.php';
            $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/customer-approval-order.php';
            $this->placeholders   = array(
                '{site_title}'   => $this->get_blogname(),
                '{order_date}'   => '',
                '{order_number}' => '',
            );

            // Triggers for this email.
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_customer-approval_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_customer-approval_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_customer-approval_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );

            // Call parent constructor.
            parent::__construct();
        }

        /**
         * Get email subject.
         *
         * @since  3.1.0
         * @return string
         */
        public function get_default_subject() {
            return __( '{site_title}] Customer Approval Needed ({order_number}', 'woocommerce' );
        }

        /**
         * Get email heading.
         *
         * @since  3.1.0
         * @return string
         */
        public function get_default_heading() {
            return __( 'Customer Approval Needed', 'woocommerce' );
        }

        /**
         * Trigger the sending of this email.
         *
         * @param int            $order_id The order ID.
         * @param WC_Order|false $order Order object.
         */
        public function trigger( $order_id, $order = false ) {
            $this->setup_locale();

            if ( $order_id && ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            }

            if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
                $this->object                         = $order;
                $this->recipient                      = $this->object->get_billing_email();
                $this->placeholders['{order_date}']   = wc_format_datetime( $this->object->get_date_created() );
                $this->placeholders['{order_number}'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
            }

            if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->get_recipient() ) {
                $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
            }

            $this->restore_locale();
        }

        /**
         * Get content html.
         *
         * @access public
         * @return string
         */
        public function get_content_html() {
            return wc_get_template_html(
                $this->template_html, array(
                    'order'         => $this->object,
                    'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
                    'sent_to_admin' => false,
                    'plain_text'    => false,
                    'email'         => $this,
                )
            );
        }

        /**
         * Get content plain.
         *
         * @access public
         * @return string
         */
        public function get_content_plain() {
            return wc_get_template_html(
                $this->template_plain, array(
                    'order'         => $this->object,
                    'email_heading' => $this->get_heading(),
                    'sent_to_admin' => false,
                    'plain_text'    => true,
                    'email'         => $this,
                )
            );
        }
    }

endif;

return new WC_Email_Customer_Approval_Order();
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us little bit more code? Maybe from your custom email class? Because with the current information it is almost impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that WooCommerce would first look through the WooCommerce plugin directory then look in the theme directory for the template.

Once I put my template in my theme directory it is working as it should.

[Solved Template Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJDMl.jpg)